# Generic Property Setter for Generic Type in C# Class

Tags: c#, generics, mapping

I am trying to Generically set the Field Values in the ItemsRow class (and others that are similar in format - but properties and fields are different.

I want to do something like what I do with hard coding

```
public Dictionary<object, Action<T, object>> SetFieldValues = new Dictionary<object, Action<T, object>>
{
 {"Description", (m,v) => m.Description = (string)v};
}


public class Mapping<T> where T:Row
{


public Dictionary<object, Action<T, object>> SetFieldValues(string[] headers)
{
        Dictionary<object, Action<T, object>> myDict = new Dictionary<object, Action<T, object>>();

        //  Activator 
        var objectType = typeof(T); // Type.GetType(T);

        var tRow = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType) as Row;

        foreach (var item in headers)
        {
            var myfield = tRow.FindFieldByPropertyName(item);
            //myDict[item] = myfield = 
            //myDict[item] = (m, v) => m.FindFieldByPropertyName(item) = (Type.GetType(myfield.Type.ToString()))v;
        }

         // I want this to be dynamic header[i],(m,v) => m.(property to set for object) = (cast to type m.property type)v
        //{"ItemName", (m,v) => m.ItemName = (string)v},
        //{"Description", (m,v) => m.Description = (string)v},



        return myDict;

}
```

// Class names will be different, properties and fields will be different..

```
  public sealed class ItemsRow : Row
   {

        public String ItemName
        {
            get { return Fields.ItemName[this]; }
            set { Fields.ItemName[this] = value; }
        }

        public String Description
        {
            get { return Fields.Description[this]; }
            set { Fields.Description[this] = value; }
        }


        public static readonly RowFields Fields = new RowFields().Init();

        public ItemsRow()
            : base(Fields)
        {
        }

        public class RowFields : RowFieldsBase
        {
            public StringField ItemName;
            public StringField Description;
    }
}
```

Base Class

=================================================================================

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Serenity.Data
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonRowConverter))]
    public abstract partial class Row : IEntityWithJoins, 
        INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject
#if !COREFX
        , IDataErrorInfo
#endif
    {
        internal RowFieldsBase fields;
        internal bool[] assignedFields;
        internal Hashtable dictionaryData;
        internal bool ignoreConstraints;
        internal object[] indexedData;
        internal bool tracking;
        internal bool trackWithChecks;

        protected Row(RowFieldsBase fields)
        {
            if (fields == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("fields");

            this.fields = fields.InitInstance(this);

            TrackAssignments = true;
        }

        public void CloneInto(Row clone, 
            bool cloneHandlers)
        {
            clone.ignoreConstraints = ignoreConstraints;

            foreach (var field in GetFields())
                field.Copy(this, clone);

            clone.tracking = tracking;
            if (tracking)
            {
                if (assignedFields != null)
                {
                    clone.assignedFields = new bool[assignedFields.Length];
                    Array.Copy(assignedFields, clone.assignedFields, assignedFields.Length);
                }
            }
            else
                clone.assignedFields = null;

            clone.trackWithChecks = trackWithChecks;

            clone.originalValues = originalValues;

            if (dictionaryData != null)
                clone.dictionaryData = (Hashtable)this.dictionaryData.Clone();
            else
                clone.dictionaryData = null;

            if (indexedData != null)
            {
                clone.indexedData = new object[indexedData.Length];
                for (var i = 0; i < indexedData.Length; i++)
                    clone.indexedData[i] = indexedData[i];
            }
            else
                clone.indexedData = null;

            if (previousValues != null)
                clone.previousValues = previousValues.CloneRow();
            else
                clone.previousValues = null;

            if (cloneHandlers)
            {
                clone.postHandler = this.postHandler;
                clone.propertyChanged = this.propertyChanged;

                if (this.validationErrors != null)
                    clone.validationErrors = new Dictionary<string, string>(this.validationErrors);
                else
                    clone.validationErrors = null;
            }
        }

        public Row CloneRow()
        {
            var clone = CreateNew();
            CloneInto(clone, true);
            return clone;
        }

        public virtual Row CreateNew()
        {
            if (fields.rowFactory == null)
                throw new NotImplementedException();

            return fields.rowFactory();
        }

        internal void FieldAssignedValue(Field field)
        {
            if (assignedFields == null)
                assignedFields = new bool[fields.Count];

            assignedFields[field.index] = true;

            if (validationErrors != null)
                RemoveValidationError(field.PropertyName ?? field.Name);

            if (propertyChanged != null)
            {
                if (field.IndexCompare(previousValues, this) != 0)
                {
                    RaisePropertyChanged(field);
                    field.Copy(this, previousValues);
                }
            }
        }

        public Field FindField(string fieldName)
        {
            return fields.FindField(fieldName);
        }

        public Field FindFieldByPropertyName(string propertyName)
        {
            return fields.FindFieldByPropertyName(propertyName);
        }

        public RowFieldsBase GetFields()
        {
            return fields;
        }

        public int FieldCount
        {
            get { return fields.Count; }
        }

        public bool IsAnyFieldAssigned
        {
            get
            {
                return tracking && assignedFields != null;
            }
        }

        public bool IgnoreConstraints
        {
            get { return ignoreConstraints; }
            set { ignoreConstraints = value; }
        }

        public string Table
        {
            get { return fields.TableName; }
        }

        public bool TrackAssignments
        {
            get
            { 
                return tracking;
            }
            set 
            {
                if (tracking != value)
                {
                    if (value)
                    {
                        if (propertyChanged != null)
                            previousValues = this.CloneRow();

                        tracking = value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tracking = false;
                        trackWithChecks = false;
                        assignedFields = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public bool TrackWithChecks
        {
            get 
            {
                return tracking && trackWithChecks;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != TrackWithChecks)
                {
                    if (value && !tracking)
                        TrackAssignments = true;

                    trackWithChecks = value;
                }
            }
        }

        private Field FindFieldEnsure(string fieldName)
        {
            var field = FindField(fieldName);
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, field))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("fieldName", String.Format(
                    "{0} has no field with name '{1}'.", this.GetType().Name, fieldName));
            return field;
        }

        public object this[string fieldName]
        {
            get 
            {
                var field = FindFieldByPropertyName(fieldName) ??
                    FindField(fieldName);

                if (ReferenceEquals(null, field))
                {
                    if (dictionaryData != null)
                        return dictionaryData[fieldName];

                    return null;
                }

                return field.AsObject(this); 
            }
            set
            {
                (FindFieldByPropertyName(fieldName) ?? 
                    FindFieldEnsure(fieldName)).AsObject(this, value);
            }
        }

        public void SetDictionaryData(object key, object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                if (dictionaryData == null)
                    return;
                dictionaryData[key] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (dictionaryData == null)
                    dictionaryData = new Hashtable();
                dictionaryData[key] = value;
            }
        }

        public object GetDictionaryData(object key)
        {
            if (dictionaryData != null)
                return dictionaryData[key];

            return null;
        }


        internal void SetIndexedData(int index, object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                if (indexedData == null)
                    return;

                indexedData[index] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (indexedData == null)
                    indexedData = new object[this.FieldCount];

                indexedData[index] = value;
            }
        }

        internal object GetIndexedData(int index)
        {
            if (indexedData != null)
                return indexedData[index];

            return null;
        }

        public bool IsAssigned(Field field)
        {
            if (assignedFields == null)
                return false;

            return assignedFields[field.index];
        }

        public void ClearAssignment(Field field)
        {
            if (assignedFields == null)
                return;

            assignedFields[field.index] = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < assignedFields.Length; i++)
                if (assignedFields[i])
                    return;

            assignedFields = null;
        }

        public bool IsAnyFieldChanged
        {
            get
            {
                if (originalValues == null)
                    return false;

                for (var i = 0; i < fields.Count; i++)
                    if (fields[i].IndexCompare(originalValues, this) != 0)
                        return true;

                return false;
            }
        }

        IDictionary<string, Join> IHaveJoins.Joins
        {
            get { return fields.Joins; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly. Your problem is that in your example you have hardcoded the propertyname "description" and its function on how to assign a value. This is what you wish to create generically. Correct?

Comment: @DaveyvanTilburg yes currently it is hard coded and I would like to be really generic as I would like to be DRY , and that way I can send whatever I want into it and it will assign regardless of type as long as the strings I have passed via headers variable line up. .

Comment: Oh yeah I think I know a solution for that, I'll get back to you with an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I couldn't get back to you yesterday, but a promise is a promise :). And while writing this code I began to doubt about what your headers actually look like. How are you going to determine which property belongs to which header? Unless you have some type of recognition for that which I might be missing from your code.

But the general idea is this:

Of course this is based on the premise that headers are keyvaluepairs of which the key is the identifier for which property to use.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        ["Title"] = "Test",
        ["Amount"] = "5",
        ["Description"] = "Some description"
    };

    var target = new TestClass();
    var setters = GetPropertySetters(target);

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> value in values)
    {
        if (setters.ContainsKey(value.Key))
            setters[value.Key].Invoke(value.Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(target));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static Dictionary<string, Action<string>> GetPropertySetters<T>(T source)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        result.Add(pi.Name, (string value) => { pi.SetValue(source, Convert.ChangeType(value, pi.PropertyType)); });

    return result;
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The headers will match the property names. I have a spreadsheet with headers , and there are different types to import via the web app. Passing in the headers will allow me to set column / row values dynamically and not require hard coding to the individual Row Classes that I have . So for the column header , I can read excel row and set it to the class. If I had only one class no biggie - hard code and done.  I appreciate you getting back to me with this too ..I will test it .

Comment: Nice! Let me know if there is still something I can do for you on this question. But I think you have it figured out with the matching of the names @Ken